# How to Change selected Cell data permanently?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I want to change the selected cell data permanently as i have done in my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method but the problem is that when I select a row the cell data is change but when i select any other row the previous become as it was, and I also want to save rows in an array, those been selected in an array. here is my code right now.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
@try {
    static NSString *cellidentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *cellObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (UITableViewCell*) [cellObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    UILabel *label;
    long row = [indexPath row];

    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:10];

    label.text =time[row];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.imageView.image = [img_clock_blue objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];

    //int hecValue;
    return cell;
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",exception);
}
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView reloadData];
UITableViewCell *cell1 = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell1.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1_red.png"];
cell1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: if you need to keep the previously selected cell as it is, you need to keep a track of it. and now you are reloading the table in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, so the previously selected will be reloaded.

Comment: @Nasir this happens because of you are reloading tableview every time after selecting the road just remove the line [tableView reloadData]; and try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

1. create a `NSMutableArray` `@property` in view controller. lets say `selectedIndexArray`
2. initialize the array in `viewDidLoad` by `self.selectedIndexArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //other codes
    if ([self.selectedIndexArray containsObject:indexPath]) {
         cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1_red.png"]; //assumes all selected cells have same image
    } else {

         cell.imageView.image = [img_clock_blue objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    .....//other code
}
```

in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.selectedIndexArray addObject:indexPath];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Comment: @Akhilrajti i also want to save which row have been selected in an array.

Comment: in `self.selectedIndexArray` you have all index of selected cells.

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying the cell, which is a bad idea. You need to modify the place where it's getting its data.

in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`just find the `objectAtIndex:`in the array, modify it to your will, then reload the table.

If you only have, for example, titles (`NSStrings`), then an array of strings will suffice. But most of the time it won't, because you're displaying something custom.

it looks like you don't have a custom class here, so I'll just make an example that you can translate easily. Let's say you're tryign to display a list of `Animal` objects.

Create your `Animal` class inheriting from NSObject. (New file, class, and so on).

Add the properties you will need in the `Animal.h` file, for example

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) int size;
@property (nonatomic) int weight;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *countryOfOrigin;
```

You'll also technically need a class to create/manage/fetch/save these `Animal` objects but let's keep it simple and do it in the `viewDidLoad` of your controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   Animal *myAnimal = [[Animal alloc]init];
   myAnimal.name = @"Lion";
   myAnimal.size = 13;
   myAnimal.weight = 100;
   myAnimal.countryOfOrigin = @"NoIdeaHahahah";

    // You can hardcode a couple like that, and add them to your array used for your tableview data. Basically we just want some of your custom objects in an array, for your tableview.
  }
```

Ok so now we have an array of Animal (our data) for your tableview. You can use that to create your rows.

When creating the cell in the `cellForRow`, simply start with :

```
Animal *animal = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and then feed your  cells with the properties of that animal

```
cell.titleLabel.text = animal.name;
```

for example.

And in the `didSelect` you can modify that specific animal, like I said at the very beginning of this answer :)

```
Animal *animal = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
animal.name = @"IJustChangedTheName";   

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

All this is common practice, except what we did in the `viewDidLoad` that is very brutal, but I'm sure you'll be able to adapt that to your code :)

Answer (score 0):

The code for setting up cell contents should all be in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

You should create a real data model to represent the contents of your cells instead of the `time` array.  Create an array of custom objects (or dictionaries) with properties such as "time" and "selected".  Use `indexPath.row` to find the correct object and then use its "selected" property to decide which kind of image to give it.

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` sets "selected" YES or NO and doesn't need to change the cell at all.